# Copying lines into python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that copies every other line from `thisFile.txt` into `thatFile.txt`, but right now, I'm just having trouble getting the lines from `thisFile.txt` to copy into `thatFile.txt`.

I have two different methods that I'm trying to use to copy, one that is commented out and the other that's in a for loop before the commented section.

```
file_one=open('thisFile.txt','w+')
file_two=open('thatFile.txt','w+')

file_one.write('Hello\nHow\nAre\nYou')

for line in file_one:
    file_two.write(line)

#line=' '
#while line !='':
#    line=file_one.readline()
#    file_two.write(line)

file_one.close()
file_two.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've opened both files for reading and writing, but after writing to the first file are expecting to read from that file immediately.  The file pointer is at the end of the file.  If you `.seek(0)` back to the beginning of the file it will work:

```
file_one=open('thisFile.txt','w+')
file_two=open('thatFile.txt','w+')

file_one.write('Hello\nHow\nAre\nYou')

# rewind the file to prep for read.
file_one.seek(0)

for line in file_one:
    file_two.write(line)

file_one.close()
file_two.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the first question (copying all lines). You need to open the file you want in `mode='r'` then write to the next file which is open with `mode='w'` (or simply `'r'` and `'w'`).

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for line in lines:
            f2.write(line)
```

For the first file you take `readlines()` to actually read every single line.

To address the second issue (every other line):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for i,line in enumerate(lines):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                f2.write(line)
            else:
                pass
```

You just need to implement `enumerate()` to loop through the list and provide only the lines whose keys are even. You can change to odd of course.